# For .pcap file, whether a swapped magic_number 0xd4c3b2a1 effect the network packet?

Tags: pcap

For example, when the magic_number is *0xa1b2c3d4*, the ether_type is *0x0008*.

Then, if the magic_number is *0xd4c3b2a1*, will the e**ther_type** be *0x0800*?

I only have **.pcap** files that the magic_number is *0xa1b2c3d4*, so I cann't verify myself.

Or someone may upload a *.pcap* file whose magic_number is *0xd4c3b2a1*, then I can analysis myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [tcpdump manpage](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-savefile.5.txt) :

That allows software reading the file to determine
whether the byte order of the host that wrote the file is the  same  as
the  byte  order  of the host on which the file is being read, and thus
whether the values in the per-file and ***per-packet*** headers  need  to  be
byte-swapped.

I think the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

The Ethernet type field is always in big-endian ("network") byte order in a packet, so, to read it, you must convert it from big-endian byte order to your machine's byte order, using, for example, `ntohs()`.

This is independent of the byte order of the host that wrote the file; using `ntohs()` will work on all machines with all pcap files.

(Bear in mind, however, that there are machines on which you would have to fetch the Ethernet type field - or any other multi-byte integral field - a byte at a time and assemble those bytes into the value, because those machines trap on unaligned memory accesses.  See, for example, the `EXTRACT_` macros/functions in `extract.h` in the tcpdump source.)

Comment: I think I gave an inappropriate example. Let we discuss the `tot_len` field of ip header, whether the `tot_len` field is always in big-endian ("network") byte order in a packet? In `0xa1b2c3d4` pcap file, I read the value is `0x4c02`. Then, if in `0xd4c3b2a1` pcap file, will it be `0x024c`?

Comment: Yes, it's always in big-endian byte order.  [RFC 791, Appendix B](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc791#page-39) says "When
a multi-octet quantity is transmitted the most significant octet is
transmitted first." - that's big-endian byte order.  Therefore *all* multi-octet quantities in the IPv4 header are transmitted in big-endian order.  This means that the byte order of the field is *THE SAME* regardless of the magic number in the pcap file.